# Android: Start animation after fragment is completely loaded

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have a fragment that has an animation of textView fadein. The animation must start after some time delay say 2 seconds after fragment is loaded. I wrote a code for this. but the animation part is done and then the view is rendered. How can I load the fragment and after some time delay start my animation

My code is as below: **Note:** the class extends **Fragment**

```
Animation animFadein;
MenuClickHelper mClickHelper;
TextView tv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu,
            container, false);

    mClickHelper = new MenuClickHelper(rootView, getFragmentManager());

    tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvPresentation);
    animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);

    animFadein.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (animation == animFadein) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Animation Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        tv.startAnimation(animFadein);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Have you got any perfect solution?

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep(2000);` dont block your main using the **sleep** method instead you can use the Handler class and use postdelay to delay the animation:

**sample:**

change this:

```
 try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    tv.startAnimation(animFadein);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    tv.startAnimation(animFadein);
  }
}, 2000); //will start animation in 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result with

```
android:startOffset="2000"
```

in your XML animation set file.